# Can a .exe file scanned and verified safe by many antivirus hack my personal information?

Tags: javascript, virus

I recently downloaded a .exe file from a person's github. I scanned the file in virustotal.com and it showed none of the antiviruses detected a virus. When I checked its behaviour, it had access to network adapters. Nevertheless, I opened the .exe but it just opened a terminal and showed something and disappeared. When I asked the guy who sent it to me, he said the program just hacked my personal information from my computer. But the antivirus shows no risk. Can anybody help me with this?

Giving the file link below:

https://github.com/constantinDev/hacktoolv2/blob/master/Tools/GTool/bin/gtool-src-win.exe?raw=true

I have a Windows 10 PC and I was connected to internet at the time of the incident and the program ran in administrator mode.

Comment: A 12 year old could bypass any antivirus in the world for less than $100. Antivirus only protects against those who can't even put in the bare minimum effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Online antivirus scanners detect **known** malware.
New malware is not known to them, so it is absolutely possible to have malware that is not detected by any antivirus.

An antivirus installed on your PC can use some more heuristics to detect potentially bad behavior of running software, but this is far from perfect.

You should absolutely not run executable software which you don't trust, and **never** run anything that is not 100% trustworthy with administrator permissions.

If you look at the [source](http://web.archive.org/web/20200812125425/https://github.com/constantinDev/hacktoolv2/blob/master/Tools/GTool/src/main.js) in the repo, this is pretty harmless, it just sends your IP and some system data to a telegram channel. Probably created by a bored teenager.

If the source code actually is the one used to create the executable you ran, that is. I didn't bother to verify that.

Comment: Can anyone tell me if this is dangerous?If the ip  address and system data is shared,is there any problem?

Comment: @bumane If the source code in the repo is the real source code for the EXE file you ran, then like Josef said, reinstate Monica, and also it's pretty harmless.

Comment: @Josef says Reinstate Monica what’s your source for the assertion that virustotal detects 99% only known malware? It’s definitely not true. Write yourself a simple keylogger in C++ and I assure you that it will be detected.

Comment: @dmuensterer i already wrote more than one keylogger which was not detected by any online scanner and even some which where not detected by a antivirus on the target system using all its heuristical magic.

Comment: @JosefsaysReinstateMonica You do know that virustotal is essentially a target system running multiple anti-virus software right? And also: I didn't say it would detect everything. I said, the chance of detection of very simple viruses is very high through heuristics.

Comment: @dmuensterer so you agree that non trivial unknown viruses will not be detected? Are you aware that Virustotal is not executing the uploaded files, and so most of the heuristic detection functions of the anti-virus scanners are not used?

Comment: @JosefsaysReinstateMonica, yes, I agree that complicated, yet unknown malware is likely not to be detected. What is your source for the provided claim that virustotal does not execute files?